# PHP multiple curl/file_get_contents() with cron, high cpu usage

Tags: php, curl, cpu

I have about 8 cron tasks running every minute, every one of them takes time as they download data from other website by curl (single script makes multiple curl requests). Is there any way to lower the cpu or memory usage? Does unstetting variables help?

Comment: 8 crons, every minute, each one with multiple requests.. don't you think they should be *allowed* some CPU time? also, AFAIK curl is more of a network hog instead of CPU. probably there's something else in your code that could be improved - if we could see the code. but in general: this question is quite *broad*. possibly *too broad*.

Comment: This is very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , unsetting variables will lower the memory usage.

If you want to lower the cpu usage you have to give them fewer tasks per second. You can start each of your scripts after some time intervals. Since each script make multiple requests that would be the best way. 
The bottleneck here should be the I/O usage , not the cpu , basically if its not going at 100% , You dont have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. Would it also help if I moved some cron tasks and put them on different server? Currently all those tasks fetch urls which are on the same server (same server as the cron tasks).

Comment: FYI : If you are new to Stack Overflow, there is a check mark near the answer to accept it if it helped. Im saying this because I didn't know about it when I was new , until someone said it :)